# C# How to pass model to Vue + typescript?

Tags: c#, typescript, vue.js

Assuming I have following *.cshtml file with my object already in place (@Model.Configuration) I would like to have it in the rendered Vue.js page built with type script (App.vue or Home.vue). How to do it for `first-name` id or it's easier to do with `window.Configuration` ?

`*.cshtml`

```
@model Views.Home.HomeViewModel;

@{
    var cdnPath = @Model.Configuration.Path;
}
<html>
<head>
    <title>@Model.Configuration.Lastname page</title>
    <link href="@(cdnPath)js/app.js" rel="preload" as="script">
    <link href="@(cdnPath)js/chunk-vendors.js" rel="preload" as="script">
    <link rel=stylesheet href="@(cdnPath)css/chunk-vendors.css" />
    <link rel=stylesheet href="@(cdnPath)css/app.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="configuration">
        <p id="first-name">@Model.Configuration.Firstname</p>
    </div>
    <div id="app">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@(cdnPath)js/chunk-vendors.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@(cdnPath)js/app.js"></script>
    <script>window.Configuration = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.Configuration));</script>
 </body>
```

`main.ts`

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import dictionary from "./dictionary";
import './plugins/coreui'
import './plugins/bootstrap-vue'
   
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Comment: Is your vue app a Single Page Application? If so, why are you using SPA with MVC Views?

Comment: I will be honest - I don't know. How I can then use SPA (without MVC Views) and pass model to Vue? I'm more a backend guy and struggling with this. Any reference links would be extreme helpful.

Comment: To know if you're an SPA, ask yourself: does my Vue application, once loaded in the browser, inspect the url and take action based on that, such as showing a different page? And, does navigating to a different page change the browser url but doesn't cause the cshtml view to render again?  ---  In c#, your view model is "configuration", but what is in that data that can't be served as a static (json) file or authentication related?

Comment: However, to address the immediate question, yes, you can do what you're doing. You will need to print out each property of `@Model...` into HTML elements, and then read those elements in Vue. I'm just not convinced that you _should_ be using c# for rendering the Vue html page at all.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't precise. "Idk" was related to "If so, why are you using SPA with MVC Views", it is a SPA. In the Model there is application tenant configuration that comes from X. This is an existing app, I just want to pass an object to Vue so the frontend developer can use model configuration to properly build backend calls.

Comment: "You will need to print out each property of @Model... into HTML elements, and then read those elements in Vue." How to actually do that?